# how to convert attribute of a relation into string in pig

Tags: apache-pig

```
c1 = LOAD 'hdfs://localhost:9000/PigData/patient.txt' USING PigStorage(',') 
as (age:int,gender:chararray,zipcode:int); 
c2 = LOAD 'hdfs://localhost:9000/PigData/att1' USING PigStorage(',') as (att:chararray,cnt:int);
res = FOREACH c2 generate $0;
%declare zip res.$0;
final = group c1 by $zip;
dump final;
```

i want to store atrribute as a vaue in a variable , then group the data with the help of that variable without mentioning the value directly..

Comment: res relation has the value (zipcode), I want to group  c1 relation with this res value.  %declare zip res.$0;  I tried with this code but  I am getting Error over here.

Answer (score 1):

Prefix the attribute with `(chararray)`.Assuming you would like to cast zipcode to string.See [here](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#Cast+Operators) for cast documentation

```
c2 = FOREACH c1 GENERATE c1.age,c1.gender,(chararray)c1.zipcode;
DESCRIBE C2;
```

Group by zipcode

```
c1 = LOAD 'hdfs://localhost:9000/PigData/patient.txt' USING PigStorage(',') as (age:int,gender:chararray,zipcode:int);
c2 = LOAD 'hdfs://localhost:9000/PigData/att1' USING PigStorage(',') as (att:chararray,cnt:int);
final = group c1 by c1.zipcode;
dump final;
```

Comment: Thank u for your reply

Comment: @RPadmaja You dont need that statement.Just use zipcode to group by.